# trouble using create method with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I am trying to use AJAX functionality in order to create a new Task in a simple ToDo list application.

Currently the list is set up like this:

```
<h2> TO DO </h2>
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul id="incomplete">
    <% @task.each do |f| %>
    <% if f.complete == false %>
      <div id="<%= f.id %>">
        <p class= "title"><%= f.title %></p>
        <%= form_for f, remote: true do |task| %>
          <%= task.check_box :complete, class: "check_box" %>
          <%= task.submit %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
      <% end %>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
<h2> COMPLETED </h2>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <ul id="completed">
    <% @task.each do |f| %>
    <% if f.complete == true %>
      <div id="<%= f.id %>">
         <p class="title"><%= f.title %></p>
        <%= form_for f, remote: true do |task| %>
          <%= task.check_box :complete, class: "check_box" %>
          <%= task.submit %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <p id="new_link"><%= link_to "New Task", new_task_path, remote: true %></p>
  <div id="new_task">
  </div>
```

When the "New Task" link is pressed, it executes a js file which loads the following partial:

```
<%= form_for @task, remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :title %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>
  <%= f.submit "Create" %>
<% end %>
```

My create method is below:

```
def create
    @task = Task.new(task_params)
    @task.save


    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  end
```

When I remove the "remote: true" from my partial form, page resets and the new task appears in the new , however, when I do use the "remote: true", and execute my create.js.erb file, nothing is changed in the DOM. Here is my create.js.erb file:

```
$('#incomplete').append($("#<%= @task.id %>"));
console.log("<%= @task.title %> has been saved.");
```

I'm not receiving any errors in my consoles, and the console.log line on the create.js.erb logs to the console without a problem the task title and the rest of the string.

I'm pretty lost in why the create.js.erb file is not manipulating the DOM. This code provides no response visually, only the post to the console.

Comment: If you can see the console log printed, then it means your first statement is not able to find an element. Either the `$('#incomplete')` or `$("#<%= @task.id %>")`

Comment: Also you are creating a new task in your controller but i don't see you creating the corresponding html element with task's id that you are trying to append. Before append you need to build that html element.

Comment: Can you try this: `$('#incomplete').append($("<div id='<%= @task.id %>'><%= @task.title %></div>"))`

Comment: I agree with @JagdeepSingh here, the problem is in your JS file not your controller.

Comment: The js that you asked me to try does work, appending just the title of the task to the incomplete list. However, I wanted to have the full div appended, along with the check/submit buttons to toggle the complete attribute. I thought that by using the same id as on the index page ('#<%= @task.id %>'), it would appear as the full div.

Comment: I think I was able to fix this problem by creating a partial that was rendered and appended by the create.js.erb file. This seems to work as of now. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @snovosel Debugging SJR templates is **hard**. I find it helpful to wrap my JS code in a try-catch block so that I can see any JavaScript errors that might be preventing my code from executing. In your case, you might be able to see why the first line does not work as you expect. Hope that helps! You can read more about my SJR debugging strategy [here](http://www.carlosramireziii.com/a-step-by-step-guide-to-debugging-sjr-templates.html?utm_source=stackoverflow) if you'd like.